# Why are the visited link colors swapped?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

In the [main list of questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), we have dark blue for visited and light blue for not. Okay. But in the [related tab for any question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24681/charles-barkley-syndrome), it's light blue for visited and dark blue for not.

This is seriously confusing me. Argh.

Comment: +1 It's a user experience snafu. And the jury is [still out on the link colours in posts](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/it-is-possible-to-change-the-colors-of-hypertext-links)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a UX snafu. The fix will be in the next production build.

Comment: :) Thanks! Would it be extremely greedy to ask you to take a look at the meta question I've linked to above and more importantly at the related [ux se question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14194/how-to-determine-whether-links-have-enough-contrast)? I'd love to get your feedback.

Comment: @YannisRizos sure. I'll be fixing a bunch css bugs on my backlog this xmas!

Comment: Well, thanks again :)